# Is there a JS code that i can use to calculate age in Azure Logic App?

Tags: javascript, azure-logic-apps

Is there a JS code that i can use to calculate age based on birthday in Azure Logic Apps?

[image]

I already tried this one (it doesn't work for me):

```
function calculate_age(dob) { 
    var diff_ms = Date.now() - dob.getTime();
    var age_dt = new Date(diff_ms); 

    return Math.abs(age_dt.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}

calculate_age(new Date(workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.profile.birthYear, workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.profile.birthMonth, workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.profile.birthDay));
```

Outputs :{"body":null}

Comment: Your JS code is perfectly fine, I just tested it. However, the month is 0-indexed, so instead of 1-12 it's 0-11. So, you might want to create DOB using `birthMonth - 1`.

Comment: thanks Maxim , but where can i add birthMonth - 1 ?

Comment: `calculate_age(new Date(workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.profile.birthYear, workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.profile.birthMonth - 1, workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.profile.birthDay));`

Comment: same output : {"body":null}

Comment: I didn't say that it's going to fix your body null problem. That's a fix for another issue in your code. Other than that, your JS if perfectly fine, so the problem is probably with how you get/output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you just need to add `return` before the last line.

```
function calculate_age(dob) { 
    var diff_ms = Date.now() - dob.getTime();
    var age_dt = new Date(diff_ms); 

    return Math.abs(age_dt.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}

return calculate_age(new Date(workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.profile.birthYear, workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.profile.birthMonth - 1, workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.profile.birthDay));
```

And be careful that the month is 0-indexed as Maxim mentioned.

When you want to get the result, you can do it as below screenshot:
[image]
The whole expression is:

```
string(outputs('Execute_JavaScript_Code')?['body'])
```

Hope it helps~